# Why React imports interfaces but not classes

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I have a React app organized as monorepo with several workspaces (sub-folders) and single node modules folder in the root. Some workspaces depend on other workspaces using this [syntax](https://yarnpkg.com/features/workspaces#publishing-workspaces)

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "subSpaceA": "workspace:*",
    "subSpaceB": "workspace:^"
  }
}
```

Also, the app is using these TS configs.

**Base**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "es2016",
      "es2017.object",
      "es2017.string"
    ],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "preserveSymlinks": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "ES2019",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Subspace**

```
{
  "extends": "../../../configs/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx",
    "src/**/*.stories.tsx",
    "src/mocks/**"
  ]
}
```

In one of the subspaces, I create 1 class and 1 interface.

```
export const Name: string = "A";
export interface IDemo { name: string; }
export class Demo implements IDemo { public name = "A"; }
```

Then, try to use it in the main app.

```
import { Name } from "@subSpaceA/shared/utilities"
import { IDemo } from "@subSpaceA/shared/utilities"
import { Demo } from "@subSpaceA/shared/utilities" // Error 2305 - @subSpaceA has no exported member

const instance = new Demo();
```

Everything works fine, the build compiles, the app is running. Also, in the build folder I see that `d.ts` files and typings for this file were generated correctly and include everything: constant, interface, and the class. **The problem happens when I try to import the class.**

1. Constant `Name` is auto-suggested and auto-imported without issues.
2. Interface `IDemo` is auto-suggested by VS Code and auto-imported without issues.
3. Class `Demo` is not found, so I have to add import it manually and see error 2305

I suspect there are some settings in TS config that allow importing only interfaces. What do I need to change, most probably in the config, to **make VS Code detect that package `@subSpaceA` exports classes**?

Comment: It's possible that your main field in your "package.json" for the subSpaceA workspace is pointing to the wrong file or not set at all. Make sure you have the correct main field in your "package.json" file that points to the compiled output (for example, "build/index".js or "dist/index.js")

Comment: Does the 'main app' have its own tsconfig? What is it?

Comment: Also as @Mephisto says - this may be related to your package.json configuration. Could you include it in the question?